# Sharding collections across different servers versus the same server

Tags: mongodb

I understand that a collection can be sharded across a cluster. Does this mean that each shard is guaranteed to live on its own hardware server? Or could multiple shards share the same hardware?

If multiple shards are living on the same hardware, wouldn't it defeat the purpose of concurrency in query performance?

Comment: "*If multiple shards are living on the same hardware, wouldn't it not defeat the purpose of concurrency in query performance?*" - Yep.

Comment: Did you mean to use double negative in the last sentence?

Comment: fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both "questions" is yes. So, if you shard, you should

a) have shards on different machines (hardware)

b) have all shards as replica sets (PSS)

c) have different PSS nodes at different locations - if possible

On that c) you could have (at one location) all node#1 (of different shards) at the same location, and then all node#2s at a different location, and then node#3s again at their own location. If you lose one location (network partitioning), you still have a functioning system.